# Как задать роут, отталкиваясь от того что в адресной строке?

Tags: маршрутизация, kohana

Т.е. если урл содержит напр. test/1, как здесь `mysite.com/questions/test/1`, то для него задать нужные controller и action?

Answer (score 1):

```
Route::set('default', '(<directory>(/<controller>(/<action>(/<id>))))', array('id' => '[0-9]+',))
    ->defaults(array(
        'directory'      => null,
        'controller'    => null,
        'action'        => null,
    ));
```

Вот дефолтный роут. К Вашему случаю он не очень подходит. Судя по всему, у вас controller, action и id в uri. В Вашем подойдёт такой

```
Route::set('questions', '(<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)))', array('id' => '[0-9]+',))
    ->defaults(array(
        'controller'    => 'questions',
        'action'        => 'test',
    ));
```

Если есть ограничение на количество допустимых action (скажем, в контроллере авторизации можно только войти и выйти/login и logout), то пишем так:

```
Route::set('auth', 'auth(/<action>)')
    ->defaults(array(
        'controller'    => 'auth',
        'action'        => '(login|logout)',
    ));
```

ну и так далее.

Comment: В маршруте по умолчанию ``directory`` нету. По крайней мере, начиная с ``3.0``. Поэтому он полностью подходит под запросы ТС.  
GitHub: [bootstrap.php:138](https://github.com/kohana/kohana/blob/3.3/master/application/bootstrap.php#L138)

Comment: но данный метод в классе Request присутствует. И пользоваться им, имхо, нужно

Comment: Согласен, штука полезная для своих целей, но не подхватывается без дополнительного маршрута. Именно в этом и заключалась суть моего комментария.  
Или о каком методе речь?

Answer (score 0):

Кстати, вот что имелось в виду:

```
Route::set('test', '<question>/test/<id>',
    array(
        'question' => '[^.,;?\n]+',
        'id' => '\d+',
    ))
    ->defaults(array(
        'controller' => 'Test',
        'action'     => 'index',
    ));
```

Теперь можно много слешей делать.